# How does a CPU discover DIMM attributes?

Tags: memory, cpu

When you plug a DIMM into your motherboard, the CPU can "see" all kinds of attributes about the stick:

1. Clock rate
2. CAS Latency
3. Bank count
4. Total size
5. etc...

But I can't seem to figure out how this meta-information is exposed to the CPU. I don't see it in the DDR3 (or other DDR#) communication protocol:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_dynamic_random-access_memory#Control_signals

How is this information exposed / discovered? Over what bus and according to what protocol?